# Start-Process, set focus (?) and press key on virtual machine disconnected from RDP

Tags: powershell, build, virtual-machine, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a situation which I need some help with.

I'm running an Azure build pipeline on microsoft hosted private VM with quite a old build program/IDE which does not have any CLI.
So I have to start the program and then press a key (F10) to start the build, right now i'm using Powershell for this.

I have issues though to get this to work on the VM when I have disconnected RDP, almost always (not 100%) when I have rdp open my script works and set focus to the program and presses the key. But sometimes it doesn´t work, and it seems to always fail when the rdp is disconnected. My build fails and when I connect with RDP the window is just grey:d out and it hasn't registered any keypress.

I have found some similar threads which seems to touch upon the issue, but not any solution for Powershell.

[Setting focus to window in a virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852429/setting-focus-to-window-in-a-virtual-machine)

[Sendkeys On Disconnected RDP Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212792/sendkeys-on-disconnected-rdp-session)

One solution seems to be to redirect standard input to the started program which means we don't have to care about focusing the window, but how do I redirect a keypress to a started process with Powershell? (Any other scripting language available in azure pipelines yaml is also ok)

The best solution so far has been

```
param
(
    [string]$appName,
    [string]$key
)

$objShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$proc = Get-Process $appName
$objShell.AppActivate($proc.Id)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$keyString = "'{" + $key + "}'"
$objShell.SendKeys($keyString)
```

But as stated, this seems to only work when I have an active RDP connection (and not 100% of the time). I have also tried using SetForegroundWindow which works fine when I run the script on my own computer but not on the VM.

Many thanks
Carl

Comment: You could try to add a `Bash task` before `Powershel`l task to run the script `START C:\Windows\System32\tscon.exe  %sessionname% /dest:console`. Could you check if it could make some changes? You could refer to these two tickets: [ticket1](https://superuser.com/questions/80334/remote-desktop-connection-without-locking-the-remote-computer?rq=1) and [ticket2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102789/automated-send-keys-failing-when-no-rdp)

Comment: I actually got it working but using the solution in "ticket2" :) I created a "logoff" bat file which I run to shut down the rdp, then all my scripts run as I want to :)